# php include commenting itself out on html page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have moved my footer contents in my website to a separate file named `footer.php` as this repeats throughout all the pages.

***footer.php***

```
<?php
    echo "<footer class="footer">
              <div class="container">
                  <p class="text-muted"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
                  <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; <span id="yearfooter"> </span>. All rights reserved.</p>
              </div>
          </footer>";
?>
```

I have included the `footer.php` into my index.html using `<?php include 'footer.php';?>`

I have also created a .htaccess file with the following:

***.htaccess***

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

But, the footer is not being displayed in my index.html page. When I inspect the index.html page using firebug, I can see the php include I've give commented `<!--?php include 'footer.php';?-->`. I did not comment it in my index.html file. This is my first day using php and appreciate any help.

***UPDATE***

***footer.php***

```
<?php
    echo '<footer class="footer">
              <div class="container">
                  <p class="text-muted"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
                  <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; <span id="yearfooter"> </span>. All rights reserved.</p>
              </div>
          </footer>';
?>
```

***Update***

I've managed to get this working. There was some config issues in my php5.conf file. Removed the config I added and its working great now.

Comment: If you insist to use double quote to enclose your HTML code, make sure you escape the double quote in HTML with backslash.

Comment: You are trying to output a PHP Code from within a HTML File. Could that work? Either you remove the Entire PHP code in the footer or you change the index File to index.php.